# data target bootstrap not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a website using bootstrap, but data-target is not working properly. Here is my code:

```
     <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 


              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse"> 
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul> 
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no content inside the `button`so nothing to click to initiate the collapse otherwise it works fine.

```
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
              <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
              <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
           Click Here
          </button>
```

Or have something inside the icons

Link [testing here](http://www.bootply.com/render/bpNi4RgLrD)

Answer (score -1):

You should put `navHeaderCollapse` in an id something like

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
```

Comment: you cant have 2 classes in one div @hello